# How to Get Text From a Span Tag In Selenium Firefox C#/VB.net?

Tags: c#, vb.net, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the number from

```
 formattedforfilter="669704.39">
```

I am trying to accomplish this in vb.net but I also understand c# to can always convert it. This is what I have so far.

```
FireFoxDriver(mydriver, options).FindElement(By.CssSelector("class='weight-semibold line-height-default align-left size-default text-size-default variant-inherit numeric with-icon-space truncate svelte-1myjzud'")).ToString()
```

Note:

```
FireFoxDriver(mydriver, options)
```

This is a function that calls my Selenium driver

here is my driver function

```
Public Function FireFoxDriver(ByVal Driver As FirefoxDriver, ByVal FireOptions As FirefoxOptions)

        Dim manager As DriverManager = New DriverManager()

        Dim firefoxConfig = New FirefoxConfig()

        FireOptions.AddArgument("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5355d Safari/8536.25")
        FireOptions.AddArgument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")

        FireOptions.SetPreference("plugin.state.flash", 0)

        manager.SetUpDriver(firefoxConfig)
        ' Driver.ExecuteScript("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")

        Return Driver
    End Function
```

I tried to call the class tag from the By.CssSelector. I keep getting a error that tells me no CSS found

Comment: This is the full HYML Code

<span style="max-width: 14ch;" class="weight-semibold line-height-default align-left size-default text-size-default variant-inherit numeric with-icon-space truncate svelte-1myjzud" formattedforfilter="669704.39">669,704.39</span>